# inserting integer input from stdin into linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, stdin

I'm trying to write a program that takes reads in input from stdin and then inserts it into a linked list.

The input is going to be in the following form and it can be extremely long:

```
3,5;6,7;8,9;11,4;
```

What I want to do is to insert the two integer values separated by `;` into a struct and then go on to put that struct into a linked list data structure.

The way that I'm obtaining the input is using something like this :

```
while (sscanf(remainder, "%d,%d;%s", first, second, remainder) != null)
```

(credit to user who answered one of my previous questions)^
but i'm not sure how to actually use the "first" and "second" values that I get and insert it into the linked list.

EDIT:

I took into consideration the below comment about using strtol and for testing purposes I tried this code:

```
char str[50] = "3,5;6,7;8,9;11,4;";
char *ptr;
int ret;

ret = strtol(str, &ptr, 10);
printf("The number is %d\n", ret);
```

However, I don't know how to move onto the next integer in the string. Ideally, I'd like to be able to get both integers between the `;` instead of one at a time. How would I do this?

Comment: Do not use sscanf like this.  You are copying the string over to remainder on each iteraction, which is extremely wasteful if the input string has any length to it.  Just use `strtol`, which returns a pointer to the token (either the comma or the semi-colon) that terminates the numeric value.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with strtol but thanks for that! I will look it up on the C library. How would I use strtol to gather all the integers in a line though? And ideally, I want it to obtain both integers at the same time eg 3,5 at once

Comment: more precisely, how do I iterate through an input line using strtol?

Comment: You call it once to get the 3, then again to get the 5.  You keep calling it until the string is exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

I am just answering so that you can correlate the components.
Simply get the inputs in this way(as you know the format)

```
int first,second;
scanf("%d,%d;",&first,&second);
```

Or do it using `sscanf()` as you have mentioned in case the string is given to you beforehand.

After you have got the first and second numbers. Put them in a struct.

```
 struct two_num 
{
    int a;
    int b;
} ;
```

In the linked list you have

```
struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    struct two_num my_num;
};

struct node* head;
```

Now for each pair of numbers you will add a node to `head` and copy the two numbers in my_num struct of that node like this-

```
 add_node(struct node *head,int x,int y)
 {
     struct node *temp;
     temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     if(head==NULL)
     //error
    else
    {
        temp->my_num.first=x;
        temp->my_num.second=y;
        struct node *p=head;
        while(p!=NULL && p->next!=NULL)
          p=p->next;
        if(p==NULL)
        {
            head=p;
            head->next=NULL;
            return;
        }
        p->next=temp;
        p->next->next=NULL;
}
```

Comment: I think I understand how they all correlate. Just the implementation got a bit overwhelming. Would you know how to use `strtol` to obtain the two numbers? Like the above comment mentioned, my approach was quite wasteful and now I'm trying to use a better method

Comment: @cp101020304.: Without using strtol you can manipulate the string easily writing a small code.

Comment: @cp101020304.: As you have string then first start getting digits from the string one by one until you reach "," now after that you again start taking digits until you encounter space or a colon or a '\0'. While getting the digits you form numbers with them.